# XML and XSLT - parameter value not in XML

Tags: xml, xslt, param

I have an XML file with more than a few records and different values (like a list of items with values such as their name, number, weight, whatever). I use XSLT to show those in a form of a table on a webpage. On every single page there's a different record shown - xslt takes the value of a parameter from the webpage and then displays only the appropriate pieces of information. For example there's a webpage concerning item XYZ - only the name, number and weight of this particular item is shown.

My question is whether there is a way to show some kind of a message (like "No data is available for this item") when there's no such item in XML. It's not like the parameter is empty or null - it is still taken from the webpage. It is just that there's no such record in the XML file.

Any help, please?

You can find the code for the XML and XLS files below. I have changed the parameters/variables names and values, but everything else remains the same as in my original file.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ItemsTable>
<ItemRow>
    <item>001</item>
    <name>aaaa</name>
    <price>2402</price>
    <price2>2200</price2>
</ItemRow>
<ItemRow>
    <item>002</item>
    <name>bbbb</name>
    <price>2402</price>
    <price2>2700</price2>
</ItemRow>
<ItemRow>
    <item>003</item>
    <name>cccc</name>
    <price>2402</price>
    <price2>2003</price2>
</ItemRow>
<ItemRow>
    <item>004</item>
    <name>dddd</name>
    <price>2402</price>
    <price2>2024</price2>
</ItemRow>
```

XSL:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:param name="thisitem">XXXX</xsl:param> 
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates /> 
</xsl:template>
<xsl:decimal-format name="european" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="." /> 
<xsl:template match="/ItemsTable/ItemRow" /> 
<xsl:template match="/ItemsTable/ItemRow [ item = $thisitem ]">
<style>table.YYY { border-collapse: collapse; } table.YYY td, table.YYY th { border: 1px solid black; padding: 1em; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; } table.YYY th { background-color: #eee; } table.YYY .header { font-size: 2em; font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 1em; padding-top: 1em; } table.YYY .itemname { color: red; font-weight: bold; white-space: nowrap; } table.YYY .yellow { background-color: yellow; } table.YYY .red { background-color: red; } table.YYY .green { background-color: #40FF00; }</style> 
<html>
<body>
<table class="YYY">
<xsl:if test="string-length(name) > 0 and string-length(price) > 0 and string-length(price2) > 0" /> 
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="string-length(name) > 0 and string-length(price) > 0 and string-length(price2) > 0">
<tr>
<th>Name</th> 
<th>Price 1</th> 
<th>Price 2</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="price > price2">
<td class="red">
<xsl:value-of select="name" /> 
</td>
<td class="red">
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(price, '###.###.###', 'european')" /> 
</td>
<td class="red">
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(price2, '###.###.###', 'european')" /> 
</td>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<td class="green">
  <xsl:value-of select="name" /> 
</td>
<td class="green">
  <xsl:value-of select="format-number(price, '###.###.###', 'european')" /> 
</td>
<td class="green">
  <xsl:value-of select="format-number(price2, '###.###.###', 'european')" /> 
</td>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</tr>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<div>
  <p>No data for this item</p> 
</div>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you show the XSLT you have so far and an example of the kind of XML you have as input?

Comment: Sure. I have changed the parameter / variables names and values, but both XML and XSL are built exactly like those below.

Comment: I know - sorry, accidentaly pressed "enter". It's now in the question description since it's too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the fact that

```
<xsl:template match="/ItemsTable/ItemRow [ item = $thisitem ]">
```

is not legal in XSLT 1.0 (you can't use variables in match expressions per spec, but some processors accept them anyway), your problem here is that templates only fire when the elements that they match exist.  If there's no `ItemRow` whose `item` child is the one you're asking for, then the template will not fire at all.

Instead, you need to move the "no data for this item" logic up into a template for the parent `ItemsTable`

```
<xsl:template match="/ItemsTable">
  <xsl:variable name="matchingRows" select="ItemRow[item = $thisitem][string-length(name)][string-length(price)][string-length(price2)]"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$matchingRows">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$matchingRows"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <div>
        <p>No data for this item</p> 
      </div>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ItemRow">
  <!-- logic for each matching row here, don't need to check the
       preconditions as the template is only called for rows that match -->
</xsl:template>
```